# Why literals produce more efficient code than initializers?

Tags: swift, performance, casting, initialization

I'm reading a [book](http://ericasadun.com/2016/12/14/buy-a-book-swift-style/) on Swift, it says:

*Where possible, prefer casting or strongly typing a literal to using initializers. Initializers add an extra function call; the cast is handled at compile time. Using literals produces more efficient code:*

```
let​ t: ​UInt8​ = 0 ​// yes​
 0 ​as​ ​UInt8​ ​// yes​
 ​UInt8​(0) ​// no​
```

To me the first option is pure and good.

The 2nd option first initializes 0 *then* does an extra *casting* operation.

The 3rd option only does initialization which is all good.

So I don't understand why the 3rd option isn't recommended while the 2nd option is...

**EDIT:**

Since `Int` has a priority would this scenario also have the same answer?

```
  let​ t: ​Int​ = 0 ​
   0 ​as​ ​Int​ ​​
   ​Int​(0) ​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as​ ​UInt8​` doesn't do any "extra *casting* operation".

It's merely a type annotation as to how to interpret the integer literal.

Comment: what's the diff between the 1st and 3rd?

Comment: The third interprets the `0` as an `Int`, and passes it into the constructor of `UInt8`. The first interprets the `0` as a `UInt8` directly.

Comment: both the third or you have a typo?

Comment: Oops, typo. Fixed.

Comment: @Alexander Curious. Why do you say in the 3rd example the `0` is first interpreted as an `Int`? There are 10 `UInt8` initializers that take an integer data type, including `Int`. The `0` could be taken as any one of them.

Comment: Because `Int` is given priority over other `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` types. See here: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58c1c8fdad3f214591e48dcc

Comment: so if the constructors were all `Int`s instead of `UInt` would your answer be any different?

Comment: @Honey Hmm? What do you mean?

Comment: @Honey The first and seconds ones is are redundant type annotations do absolutely nothing, and should be avoided. The third interprets the `0` as a `Int` and then creates a `UInt8`

Comment: typo me the third is `Int(0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137703/discussion-between-alexander-and-honey).

Comment: Given we're talking about the default types of literals, may also be worth noting that the default type for a given literal is determined by type of the 'global' `XYZLiteralType` in the current module. You can declare a typealias to override the default types, e.g defining `typealias IntegerLiteralType = UInt` at the top level makes the default type for an integer literal `UInt` in the module where that typealias is defined.

Comment: @Hamish Hah! just added `typealias IntegerLiteralType = UInt` to Alexander's sandbox and saw the change. Very Swifty

Comment: The crazy things you learn when you browse through the docs directory of the Swift GitHub repo (in this case, [Literals.rst](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Literals.rst)) :D Although not that I would ever reccomend defining your own `XYZLiteralType` – I can imagine all sorts of weird confusion arising from that (*especially* due to the fact that it makes the change module-wide).

Comment: @Hamish I kind of wish Swift has a more narrow concept of a module, more like a Java Package.

Comment: Oohhh you can actually make a `XYZLiteralType` `typealias` `fileprivate` – that restricts it to a given source file (doh!). I assumed from the wording of the doc "current module-scope context" meant it had to be `internal`, that doesn't appear to be so. But even still, I would be reluctant to use it.